# Django FileField upload

Tags: django

I am quite confused.

I have wrote an upload form in my site. everything works perfectly..

however, I am reading that I needed to implement a function like handle_uploaded_file to dump the file content from the request.FILES to a physical file.

however , I didn't do it any the file exists in the location I set the upload_to in the FileField field. everything works as expected..

Am I missing something ? why do I need handle_uploaded_file then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to do a handle_uploaded_file.
When you save the object (form.save) Django already does this for you.

Look this:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L270-276

Comment: yes... I wrote, everything is working correctly. but why on the django documents it mention that I need to handle the upload by chunks by myself ? I didn't do it but still the upload works perfectly. it is located in the upload_to directory

Comment: nope. My own view. I am doing is_valid on the form and form.save(). the file is uploaded with no problem.

Comment: Oh.. so because I am using a ModelForm it is done when I save it, but if I have a form with no save , I need to do it myself... got it. Django documentation is pretty bad ...